# Magento2 : How To Get Parameters from URL In Controller

Tags: magento2, url, parameter, querystring

**http://mystagesite.com/magento232/custom/module/check/?params=<%3Fxml+version%3D"1.0"+encoding%3D"UTF-8"+standalone%3D"yes"%3F>6<%2FRESPONSECODE>Invalid+Session+Token%3A+Session+has+Timed+Out<%2FRESPONSEDESCRIPTION><%2FRESULT>**

In above url , api returns some parameters in xml format

I have to get value of params in check contoller but i have got only empty array

using this code **$this->getRequest()->getParams()**

I already tried above code but it shows empty array

if i remove first three character from parameter %3F than i got result but that parameter returns from api so can't change that one

so if anyone have idea about this than please let me know

Comment: did you try like this $this->getRequest()->getParams('params') ?

Comment: yes i already tried with that code but same result empty array

Comment: if i remove first three character from parameter %3F than i got result but that parameter returns from api so can't change that one

Comment: $this->_request->getParams() or have you test with $_GET

Comment: @AnasMansuri i already try but no result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with below code other option:

```
$url = 'http://mystagesite.com/magento232/custom/module/check/?params=<%3Fxml+version%3D"1.0"+encoding%3D"UTF-8"+standalone%3D"yes"%3F>6<%2FRESPONSECODE>Invalid+Session+Token%3A+Session+has+Timed+Out<%2FRESPONSEDESCRIPTION><%2FRESULT>';
$url_data = parse_url($url); 

parse_str($url_data['query'], $params); 

echo $params['params'];
```

**hope its work for you**

Comment: Thank you so much Work Great !!!

Answer (score 3):

**You can try with Below code:**

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
   $this->request = $request;
}

$this->request->getParam('your_param');
```

**Hope this help you!**

Comment: i also tried with this but no result empty array